# Did not recieved bit coin due to unconfirmed transaction since 2 days

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

I sent 0.305*** some bit from my block chain wallet to zebapy wallet.
Since 2 days I did not received any amount and also I can see in block chain information that 0 - pending confirmations. (0/6).

Can anyone help me how to get my money back?

https://blockchain.info/address/38QFMgBBTX8j8Zn36nuVJnaHWnWgmGmHdU